# Sharing multiple views and controllers using "ion" view calls in Ionic Project

Tags: angularjs, navigation, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I've been stuck on this issue for a week now and I feel like I understood 'ui-router' and 'ionic's' view routing but this seems not to be the case.

I've seen numerous examples how the view works but now as my build is larger, the examples I've seen are too simplistic for my project as my project has views for both a side menu, tabs, and each tabs content.

**My issue:**

I am holding more than one view with different controllers inside of my tabs. I'm working with a leaflet map and a drop down list that will be populated with my locations and I got both to work. However, the views are making weird calls. Anytime I select the leaflet map it pushes my "Discover List" (in my `discover-home.html`) button under my apps `ion-nav-bar` in my `menu.html`. In addition, you can see that this list view is in-between my map and the zoom icons and if do not touch my map and I switch tabs and come back I cannot open the list again.

**I think** the question's I need to ask to understand my problem are

**1. What is the correct way to navigate in a multi-viewed applications using ionic's view navigation?**

**2. Why does changing views disable other controllers from being called again?**

**3. What are some of the best practices?**

This is what I'm dealing with. Any help would be appreciated.

> my tab view  inside **discover-home.html**
>
> [image]
>
> Sidebar view inside **menu.html**
>
> [image]
>
> List Display inside **discover-home.html**
>
> [image]
>
> discover list in **discover-home.html** hidden under **ion-nav-bar** in **menu.html**
>
> [image]

**Here's my code snippets**

> index.html

```
 <body ng-app="starter">
     <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

> discover-tabs-controller.html

This controls the tabs views (one of which is discover-home.html)

```
    <ion-view>
      <div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only" >
     <ion-content  has-subheader="true"></ion-content>

<!--HOME TAB [OPEN]-->
    <ion-tab title="Discover" icon-on="icon ion-home" icon-off="icon ion-home" 
      href="#/app/discover/home">

      <ion-nav-view cache-view="true" name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        <!-- View For Home.html -->
      </ion-tab>
 <!--HOME TAB [CLOSED]-->  


     <!--MORE TABS HERE-->

    </ion-content>
    </ion-tabs>
      </div>
    </ion-view>
```

> Discover-home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">


<!--SUBHEADER BUTTON: DISPLAY LISTVIEW -->
    <div ng-controller="FrostCtrl" class="bar bar-subheader button bar-balanced" ng-click="pushFrost()">
        <h2 class="title">{{title}} List</h2>
    </div>



  <!--DISPLAY OVERLAY WITH LIST-->
    <ion-pane ng-controller="OverlayCtrl" class="dark-overlay" ng-show="showOverlay">

      <ion-content class="has-subheader">

        <button class="button button-block button-outline button-balanced" ng-click="hideFrost()">Dismiss
        </button>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" class="dark-item">
              {{item.text}}
           </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>




  <!--LEAFLET MAP -->
    <leaflet class="has-subheader padding"center="nassau" paths="paths" tiles="tiles" markers="markers" defaults="defaults">
      </leaflet>


</ion-view>
```

> controller.js

```
          angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
            ...


    // #######| LEAFLET MAP  |#######
        .controller('ActivityCntl', [ '$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {

           var tileSource = {
                onlineTiles: {
                    url: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" 
                },

            };

            angular.extend($scope, {

                nassau: {
                lat: 25.074521,
                lng: -77.318191,
                zoom: 13
                .........
            });
        }])


  // #######| SHOW OVERLAY  |#######
        .controller('FrostCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$compile', function($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {
          $scope.pushFrost = function() {
            var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('myPane'));
            el.attr('frost', '');
            el = $compile(el)($scope);
            $rootScope.showOverlay = true;
          };
        }])


    //#######| DISPLAYS CONTENTS |##########
        .controller('OverlayCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {
          $scope.items = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({

              text: 'Whatever ' + (i+1)

               });
          }
          $scope.hideFrost = function() {
            $rootScope.showOverlay = false;
            var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('myPane'));
          };
        })
```

> app.js

```
config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider

.state('app', {
    name: 'app',
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

.state('app.discover', {
    name: 'app.discover',
    url: "/discover",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/discover-tabs-controller.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

// for my discover-home.html
    .state('app.discover.home', {

```
url: "/home",
views: {
   'home-tab': {
   templateUrl: "templates/discover-tabs/discover-home.html",
   controller:  'ActivityCntl'
       },
       'discover-home-listview': {
   templateUrl: "templates/discover-tabs/discover-home.html",

       }
}
```

})

> menu

This controls the sidemenu items

```
    <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
      <ion-side-menu-content>

//IT GETS PUSHED UNDER THIS
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm">
          <ion-nav-back-button>
          </ion-nav-back-button>

          <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
          <h1 class="title">MYApps</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
            <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
              Login
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/discover">
             <i class="icon ion-location"></i>
              Discover
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/map">
            <i class="icon ion-map"></i>
              Map
            </ion-item>

          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
```